# Connecting console application to XConnect in Azure Sitecore 9.2

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-api

I'm using `Sitecore 9.2` scaled environment on Azure, and am trying to make a console application connects to XConnect, am following this [link](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/xconnect-tutorial--1--create-a-contact-and-an-interaction.html) from Sitecore documentation.

In the part shown in the below code, I added the search indexer server URL in the `searchWebAPIClient`. However, I'm not sure what should be defined in the other 2 `APIs (CollectionWebApiClient and ConfigurationWebApiClient)`. Also, where to define the reporting, ProcessingEngine, search indexer. server.

Can someone please advise?

```
var collectionClient = new CollectionWebApiClient(new Uri("https://collect.azurewebsites.net/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
var searchClient = new SearchWebApiClient(new Uri("https://search.azurewebsites/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
var configurationClient = new ConfigurationWebApiClient(new Uri("https://xconnect/configuration"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });

var cfg = new XConnectClientConfiguration(
            new XdbRuntimeModel(CollectionModel.Model), collectionClient, searchClient, configurationClient);
```

Comment: Please add your code as text not an image. It gives the search engines more to crawl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to copy below two connection strings from CM app service to your console app to connect to XConnect.

```
<add name="xconnect.collection"                         connectionString="https://XXXXXXXX-xc-search.azurewebsites.net" />
<add name="xconnect.collection.certificate"             connectionString="blah;blah;" />
```

and then use `xconnect.collection` connectionstring in all 3 places as shown below-

```
var xdbCollectionCert = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xconnect.collection.certificate"].ConnectionString;
var xdbClient = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xconnect.collection"].ConnectionString;
var odataEndpoint = xdbClient + "/odata";
var collectionEndpoint = xdbClient + "/configuration";

var options = CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifierOptions.Parse(xdbCollectionCert);

var certificateModifier = new CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifier(options);

var clientModifiers = new List<IHttpClientModifier> { new TimeoutHttpClientModifier(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20)) };

var collectionClient = new CollectionWebApiClient(new Uri(odataEndpoint), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
var searchClient = new SearchWebApiClient(new Uri(odataEndpoint), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
var configurationClient = new ConfigurationWebApiClient(new Uri(collectionEndpoint), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });

var cfg = new XConnectClientConfiguration(new XdbRuntimeModel(CollectionModel.Model), collectionClient, searchClient, configurationClient);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but I faced another issue when running the project it gives me an error saying (Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException: 'An error occurred while sending the request.' InvalidOperationException: The certificate was not found.) do you know what is wrong

Comment: @Fatemaelsayed Did you install xConnect's client certificate on your local? To access XConnect from your local, you will require to install client cert or you need to set AllowInvalidCertificate to true which is not recommended.

Comment: @Surya, do you know if the cert should have the private key? I'm getting the same error and my console app is running on a different VM, so I installed the cert but the private key was not exportable.

Comment: @webber private key is not required. It just require the cert to be installed on the system.

Answer (score 0):

For all of three API's we need to give XConnect hostname only as I did below.

```
 var collectionClient = new Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.CollectionWebApiClient(new Uri("https://XConnect Site hostname/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
 var searchClient = new Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.SearchWebApiClient(new Uri("https://XConnect Site hostname/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
 var configurationClient = new Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient(new Uri("https://XConnect Site hostname/configuration"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
```

Please let me know if getting any issue with it.

Comment: As I mentioned am using a scaled sitecore environment, which means that the XConnect is divided into servers reporting, ProcessingEngine, search indexer...  So I dont know which server URL to put in the CollectionWebApiClient, SearchWebApiClient, and ConfigurationWebApiClient